# Does jenkins has a way to check the status(up or down) of the selenium grid which is running in the sauce lab environment?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-grid, saucelabs

I am trying to use sauce labs with jenkins for the selenium functional test cases.

let's say I have a jenkins ci/cd pipeline in network-1 where it connects to git repo to checkout the code and do the deployment in network-2.

now after the deployment, selenium functional test cases has to run so jenkins is making connection to sauce labs

**Does jenkins has a way to check the status(up or down) of the selenium grid which is running in the sauce lab environment ?**

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Jenkins does not have a built-in Selenium grid status check.  Sauce Labs' grid has very high uptime (Which you can check at [enter link description here][4]) and scheduled maintenance windows; You can subscribe to updates at that Status page link.

If you wanted to automate this process, I'd suggest adding a test step that calls out the command-line and uses `curl` or `wget` to check the WebDriver endpoint:

`curl https://ondemand.saucelabs.com`

If that returns "OK,ondemand alive" you know that the server is at least *responding*.  This won't tell you if there's something that's not going great with the grid internally... But you could try scraping the Status page as well.

(I'm also going to recommend we add this feature to the Jenkins plugin).